# How to display time from UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I'm using a UIDatePicker in time mode to get the time. I'm trying to display the time selected in a label. The following code doesn't work

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

label.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];

[outputFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine to me.  Did you double check that your label/datepicker are linked up correctly (either through IB or however you created them)?  Also, in what way specifically does the code not work?

Comment: You were right about the link. I forgot to make the link in IB. The code works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are just trying to set the  time format in setDateFormat.

Call the below function as your selector method - Resolved.

```
- (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [df setTimeZone:@"h:mm a"];

  }
```